# how to create dropdown input like google-input-tool in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, dropdown, google-input-tools

How can I make a dropdown suggestion like google-input-tool with the input in that same as in the image below?
(I am able to get dropdown but not in the textarea while typing a word)

[image: google-input-tools]